# JWT auth dosen't create token for Custom user model in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, djoser

I have the following problem :
i created a custom UserModel and Djoser for jwt auth.
when i create a superuser by terminal it created with hashed password but when i create it with an APIVIEW it created without being hashed so when i need to create a token for created user it gives me `"detail": "No active account found with the given credentials"`
but when i create a token for the superuser it created successfully.

my custom user model:

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_("Please enter your email address"))

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        new_user = self.model(email = email, **extra_fields)
        new_user.set_password(password)
        new_user.save()

        return new_user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Super user should have is_staff True'))
        
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Super user should have is_superuser True'))

        if extra_fields.get('is_active') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Super user should have is_active True'))

        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(null=False, unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'phone_number']
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

User View:

```
class UserView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        user = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserCreationSerializer(user, many = True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserCreationSerializer(data = request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(status = status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone interested i finally figured it out.
my main problem that i didn't have a create password function s when i create a user its password didn't get hashed.
i had to add this function to my serializers.

```
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create(
            username = validated_data['username'],
            email = validated_data['email'],
            phone_number = validated_data['phone_number']
        )

        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()

        return user
```